# Difference between two rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess

Very simple, can someone tell me the difference between the following please:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap/.*$ /appindex.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap/?$ /appindex.php [L]
```

Comment: Why not you test it?

Comment: @sємsєм I have, but I'm against a tight deadline and I like the advice on here.

Comment: However, it is good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question about regular expression notation. It has little to do with the logic of rewrite rules themselves. Note that there are very good introductions to regular expressions. Also you want to use one of the online regex utilities to experiment with the patterns...

---

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap/.*$ /appindex.php [L]
```

This one matches all requests to URLs starting with the literal string `sitemap`, followed by a slash and some more but arbitrary characters.

Examples for this would be:

- `sitemap/index.xml`
- `sitemap/folder/sitemap.xml`

---

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap/?$ /appindex.php [L]
```

This one matches all requests to URLs starting with the literal string `sitemap`, potentially followed by a slash and nothing more.

The only matching examples for this obviously are:

- `sitemap`
- `sitemap/`

Note that such rules do *not* consider http get parameters, these are irrelevant at this level since they are not part of the URL itself, but arguments. So the following does *also* match:

- `sitemap?id=test`

---

Note that *both* rules only make sense when used inside `.htaccess` style files. They will *not* work inside the real http servers host configuration. That is because the real configuration works on *absolute paths*, whilst `.htaccess` style files work on *relative paths*, so paths without leading slash (`/sitemap/...` versus `sitemap/...`). In general one should *always* prefer to place rewrite rules inside the real host configuration. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they *really* slow the server down, often for nothing. They are only provided for two situations: people without access to the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers) and applications that need to dynamically updated their own configuration (which is a security nightmare, so think twice about that approach).

Comment: Could you able to add URL examples in the form of match and not match?

Comment: Thank you @arkascha